c++, sorting of custom object: requirements of the comparison function
I have a vector of pointer of a custom object std::vector<MyObject*>. The object has an index, a number and a timestamp (time of creation of the object). The timestamp is unique, the number can be either -1 (the object is not been assigned a number yet) or a positive value; if the object has a number greater than 0, the number is unique.
class MyObject {
private:
    int id;
    int number;
    time_t timestamp;
public:
    MyObject(int id, int number, time_t timestamp) : id(id), number(number), timestamp(timestamp) {}
};

I want to order the vector using a custom comparison function: if the two instances of my object have a number, I order using the number (descending), if not I order using the timestamp (descending).
So I added the following to the MyObject class:
    static bool compareByDescendingNumberAndTimestamp(MyObject * a, MyObject * b) {
        if (a->number > 0 && b->number > 0) {
            return a->number > b->number;
        }
        return a->timestamp > b->timestamp;
    }

And finally sort the vector:
std::vector<MyObject*> myObjects;
auto object1 = new MyObject(1, 24097, 1200);
auto object2 = new MyObject(2, 24096, 1100);
auto object3 = new MyObject(3, -1, 1000);
auto object4 = new MyObject(4, -1, 900);
auto object5 = new MyObject(5, 24099, 800);
auto object6 = new MyObject(6, 24095, 850);
myObjects.push_back(object1);
myObjects.push_back(object2);
myObjects.push_back(object3);
myObjects.push_back(object4);
myObjects.push_back(object5);
myObjects.push_back(object6);
std::sort(myObjects.begin(), myObjects.end(), MyObject::compareByDescendingNumberAndTimestamp);

The order I intended to have is the following:
ID   Number  Timestamp
5    24099    800
1    24097   1200
2    24096   1100
3    -       1000
4    -        900
6    24095    850

But what I actually got is:
ID   Number  Timestamp
1    24097   1200
2    24096   1100
3    -       1000
4    -        900
5    24099    800
6    24095    850

After some research I find this page. As far as I understood, my comparison function does not satisfy the requirements of Compare. In particular the comp(a, b) does not establish a strict weak ordering relation.
Is there a way I can write a comparison function to order my vector as I want?
Note: I've been using c++17.
Edit:
Minimal reproducible example (notice that the initail order of the vector influences the end result):
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

class MyObject {
public:
    int id;
    int number;
    time_t timestamp;

    MyObject(int id, int number, time_t timestamp) : id(id), number(number), timestamp(timestamp) {}

    static bool compareByDescendingNumberAndTimestamp(MyObject * a, MyObject * b) {
        if (a->number > 0 && b->number > 0) {
            return a->number > b->number;
        }
        return a->timestamp > b->timestamp;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MyObject*> myObjects;
    auto object1 = new MyObject(1, 24097, 1200);
    auto object2 = new MyObject(2, 24096, 1100);
    auto object3 = new MyObject(3, -1, 1000);
    auto object4 = new MyObject(4, -1, 900);
    auto object5 = new MyObject(5, 24099, 800);
    auto object6 = new MyObject(6, 24095, 850);
    myObjects.push_back(object6);
    myObjects.push_back(object5);
    myObjects.push_back(object4);
    myObjects.push_back(object3);
    myObjects.push_back(object2);
    myObjects.push_back(object1);
    std::sort(myObjects.begin(), myObjects.end(), MyObject::compareByDescendingNumberAndTimestamp);

    std::cout << "ID\tNumber\tTimestamp" << std::endl;
    for (auto const & object: myObjects) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(object->id) << "\t" << std::to_string(object->number) << "\t"
        << std::to_string(object->timestamp) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

EDIT 2
I have to add that, actually, no user really cares about the sorting :D I released several version of the application that we use in the company I work for (my question is a simplified version of a real business case) and nobody complained. It's just me trying to solve a "puzzle" in the most elegant way.

It is unclear after which numbered object you want to sort each unnumbered object. With a larger test case you might find your criteria to be ambiguous. This ambiguity is  likely why the comparator is non conforming.

Please post a [mcve].

if (a->number > 0 && b->number > 0) -- What happens if a is positive and b is 0 or negative (or vice-versa)?   The issue I see is your single comparison function uses two distinct sorting criteria, where one criteria has basically nothing to do with the other.   If it were "cascading", i.e. if two field items are equal, then sort on some other field, and if those fields are equal, sort on a third field, etc., then it makes sense.  But your criteria doesn't follow this pattern.

Let's just look at two elements: if you compare (24099,800) and (-1,1000), since second doesn't have a number, the second element has a higher timestamp. So it would be sorted higher, and this is the result you're getting. If you look at the result you wanted to achieve, can you describe why did you expect just these two elements sorted differently? It looks like you need to rethink the criteria

Thanks all. Actually it seems like I have to order it in two passes: first by number, than pushing the unnumbered items by the timestamp. At least that's how my human mind thinks. I wonder if there's a way to express this using a comparison function?

Maybe you should std::partition the items so that the items with valid id's are before (or after) the items without an id.   With std::partition you get an iterator that denotes where the partition occurs.  Then you can call sort on each partition.

@GiorgioR Is this what you would like to achieve?

@GiorgioR is this what you want to achieve?

In the prose description of the desired order you say how to sort numbered items and you say how to sort unnumbered items. You do not say how to sort numbered items with respect to unnumbered items. Just spell it out. And then implement the comparison function accordingly. Then you don't have to partition the data in an additional pass.

@PaulMcKenzie That could be a solution, but I realize that there's much ambiguity in the way I would like to sort the vector. So I tried to formalize it in a more rigorous form: "the vector has to be ordered first with all the numbered items in descending order. Then the unnumbered items should be placed below the first element (found iterating backwards) that has a timestamp greater than the unnumbered item itself". This https://godbolt.org/z/dv8Kzd6q8 is a working algorithm, but it seems to me really cumbersome, so any suggestion to simplify it is welcome.

@Caleth Not really, the unnumbered items should be above the item 24095

"This [...] is a working algorithm" -> except for the fact the loop of reverse iterators places unnumbered items after the last numbered item with a greater timesamp (not the first like you specify). Anyway, there is indeed a better way to write the merging nested loops (without the need for the inner loop to restart from rbegin every time) but it will remain about as complex as you wrote + you must first get your requirements straight. AFAIC, this should be a new question (this one was solely about the requirements the comparison function must meet; think about future readers).

@atmo "the unnumbered items should be placed below the first element (found iterating backwards)" Well the first element iterating backwards is the last element :)

Yes... Anyway, you can use std::make_reverse_iterator / reverseIterator.base() to switch from forward to reverse iterators and do that on the iterator passed and the iterator returned by std::vector::insert so that you can do it in 1 loop.

Before we start:
From your question:

If the two instances of my object have a number, I order using the number (descending), if not I order using the timestamp (descending).

Judging from the comments under your question, it seems people are unsure whether the 2nd part of your sentence applies only when both objects being compared have no number, leaving no clear rule for comparing an object with a number with an object with no number.
Personally, I interpret it as: if either of the 2 objects I am comparing have no number, then they are to be ordered by descending timestamp.This is consistent with what you present as the order you intended to apply (objects with ids 3 and 4 are ordered between 2 and 6 by comparison of the timestamps and ignoring the fact that only 2 of them have a number).

To answer the question in the title (requirements of the comparison function), refer to std::sort, or more precisely to the link describing the Compare requirements, that is you must provide a strict weak ordering function..
The problem with the ordering function that you describe in your question is that it is in fact not an ordering function at all.
Quick reminder of order theory, an order relation (noted ≤) must verify 3 properties:

Reflexivity: a ≤ a
Antisymmetry: if a ≤ b and b ≤ a then a = b
Transivity: if a ≤ b and b ≤ c then a ≤ c

When you have such a relation, you are guaranteed, by comparing only pairs of items, to get a sorted set and divide and conquer sorting algorithms heavily rely on these properties to be valid.
If you have not, you are likely to run into a contradiction.
Let us take 3 items, ids 2, 3 and 5 (shown as (id    number    timestamp)) and see what your function says:

(5    24099    800) ≤ (2    24096   1100) (by comparison of their numbers)
(2    24096   1100) ≤ (3    -       1000) (by comparison of their timestamps)
(3    -       1000) ≤ (5    24099    800) (by comparison of their timestamps)
(2    24096   1100) ≤ (5    24099    800) (by transivity using 2. and 3.)
(2    24096   1100) = (5    24099    800) (by antisymmetry using 1. and 4.)

And here is the contradiction. Your program will not detect it because it trusts you provide it a proper order relation.
Conclusion: you have to change your function for it to be a proper order relation (actually, C++ requires a strict order relation, therefore a < a must be false).

Now that the theory is out of the way, let us see how the myObjects vector could be sorted.
One valid ordering is:

All the objects with number == -1 (all the objects with number < 0, really) are at the end and sorted by decreasing timestamp.
All the objects with number >= 0 are sorted by decreasing number.

And this can be simplified into a sort by number, timestamp in descending order.
For safety, I will test if nullptr is encountered anywhere (which you did not do but really always should) and push them to the end (I let you change the loop to print objects).
std::sort(myObjects.begin(), myObjects.end(), 
    [] (auto const a, auto const b) -> bool {
    if (!a)
        return false;
    if (!b)
        return true;
    return std::make_pair(a->number, a->timestamp) > std::make_pair(b->number, b->timestamp);
});

Another valid ordering is:

All the objects with number < 0 are at the start and sorted by decreasing timestamp.
All the objects with number >= 0 are sorted by decreasing number.

In this case, it cannot be simplified like above and you get:
std::sort(myObjects.begin(), myObjects.end(), 
    [] (auto const a, auto const b) -> bool {
    if (!a)
        return false;
    if (!b)
        return true;
    if (a->number >= 0 && b->number >= 0)
        return a->number > b->number;
    if (a->number < 0 && b->number < 0)
        return a->timestamp > b->timestamp;
    return (a->number < 0); // we know a->number and b->number are not the same sign
});

As a more flexible alternative, you can sort in several steps, using std::partition to divide your vector into comparable sub-parts (it is more efficient than std::sort).The lambdas will be easier to write:
auto nonNullEnd = std::partition(myObjects.begin(), myObjects.end(),
    [](auto const o) -> bool {
    return static_cast<bool>(o);
});
// nonNullEnd now points to the first nullptr,
// therefore it is safe not to test pointers before it.
auto negNumberedObjectEnd = std::partition(myObjects.begin(), nonNullEnd,
    [](auto const o) -> bool {
    return o->number < 0;
});
// negNumberedObjectEnd now points to the first object with number >= 0.
// We can use it as the past-the-end iterator for objects with number < 0
// and as the begin iterator for objects with number >= 0.

std::sort(myObjects.begin(), negNumberedObjectEnd,
    [] (auto const a, auto const b) -> bool {
        return a->timestamp > b->timestamp;
});
std::sort(negNumberedObjectEnd, nonNullEnd, 
    [] (auto const a, auto const b) -> bool {
    return a->number > b->number;
});

There surely are other ways to sort things, and I recommend that last approach if you want to try them.

As I sidenote, I disagree with the "always check for nullptr". I'm either allowing nullptrs to appear, or I don't. In the second case, I might just assert that requirement, but still not handle them properly because I see absolutely no reason to waste my time supporting programming errors, and oftentimes there's no good way to handle them since the design doesn't consider them anywhere. On the other hand, something that I generally do not do is putting raw-pointers into containers -- it can happen, but it's rare.

Well, the topic of the question was not raw pointers vs smart pointers so I was not going to address this point. As for "always checking for nullptr", my intention was to highlight how the complex lambda of the single sort snippet turns in the partition snippet (I did some scroll up/revision before posting my answer, the very first version I wrote did not have that bit).

Now, you seeing absolutely no reason to [...] supporting programming errors Iooks very strong a statement to me; had you worked with a team with poor dev practice like I did long ago, you'd move heaven and earth (it is indeed a lot of work, I can give you that) to prevent idiots from breaking things down, often after 1-2 years... At least I learned there was no limit to how bad things can get right in my first job :)

@Atmo Can just document "terminates program on case of nullptr" then passing nullptrs is not programming error.
